# Fade in text word by word, start fading next word before current is fully visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make text from paragraphs fading in word by word. I searched a lot and I found some code. Code is working well, but I am trying to make next word start fading before current word is finished.

So, with current code, words are appearing one by one. Now, when current word is on about 75% opacity I want next word to start appearing, so it will look smother.

My code:

```js
var p = $(".sentences > p").hide();
(function oneParagraph(i) {
    if (p.length <= i)
        return;
    var cur = p.eq(i),
        words = cur.text().split(/\s/),
        span = $("<span>"),
        before = document.createTextNode("");
    cur.empty().show().append(before, span);
    (function oneWord(j) {
        if (j < words.length) {
            span.hide().text(words[j]).fadeIn(500, function() {
                span.empty();
                before.data += words[j]+" ";
                oneWord(j+1);
            });
        } else {
            span.remove();
            before.data = words.join(" ");
            if((p.length - 1) > i) {
              setTimeout(function(){
                p.hide();
              }, 750);
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                oneParagraph(i+1);
            }, 1000);
        }
    })(0);
})(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sentences">
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #1</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #2</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #3</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #4</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #5</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I found a way how to create effect I wanted, but now I have another problem. I don't know how to hide sentence after it is displayed.

```js
var P = $('.sentences > p');

P.hide().contents().each(function() {
    var Words;
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        Words = '<span> ' + this.data.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
        $(this).replaceWith(Words);
    } else if (this.nodeType === 1) {
        this.innerHTML = '<span> ' + this.innerHTML.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
    }
});

P.find('span').hide().each(function() {
    if( !$.trim(this.innerHTML) ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});

P.show().find('span').each(function(I) {
    $(this).delay(200 * I).fadeIn(800);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sentences">
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #1</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #2</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #3</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #4</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated question. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is waiting for the callback from the fadeIn method, what you might try is not waiting for it to finish, just create a timer that is 75% of the fadeIn time, and assign that to the next step.

//Instead of

```
span.hide().text(words[j]).fadeIn(500, function() {
                span.empty();
                before.data += words[j]+" ";
                oneWord(j+1);
            });
```

//Something Like

```
span.hide().text(words[j]).fadeIn(500);
window.setTimeout(300, function(){
    span.empty();
                before.data += words[j]+" ";
                oneWord(j+1);
});
```

Comment: This stops animation on current word and display next.